# Issue with scrapy : Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, scrapy

İ've just finished a Scrapy tutorial then i started to apply what i've learned so far in a new project. I'm trying to scrape a forum site but it basically scrapes nothing... I have checked the xpath expressions from scrapy shell and i always get the desired results but when i run the crawl command from terminal, it ends up with 0 crawled pages. After intense hours of scrapy tutorial readings and many attempts i still have no progress. What am i missing? Thanks for help

Here is the code below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class ParserSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'parser'
    allowed_domains = ['www.eksisozluk.com']
    start_urls = ['https://eksisozluk.com/basliklar/gundem']

    rules = (
        Rule((LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths="//ul[@class='topic-list']/li/a")), callback='parse_item', follow=True, ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath("//h1[@id='title']/a/text()").getall(),
            'entry': response.xpath("//div[@class='content']text()").getall(),
            'yazar': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-author']/text()").getall(),
            'title': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-date permalink']/text()").getall(),

        }
```

and output:

```
...

2021-01-11 20:05:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-01-11 20:05:46 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-01-11 20:05:46 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2021-01-11 20:05:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://eksisozluk.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-01-11 20:05:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://eksisozluk.com/basliklar/gundem> (referer: None)
2021-01-11 20:05:48 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'eksisozluk.com': <GET https://eksisozluk.com/11-ocak-2021-kabine-toplantisi-kararlari--6794884?a=popular>
2021-01-11 20:05:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-01-11 20:05:48 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 499,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 20870,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.416214,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 11, 17, 5, 48, 192682),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 54054912,
 'memusage/startup': 54054912,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 50,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 11, 17, 5, 46, 776468)}
2021-01-11 20:05:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: what do you write in your terminal to run the spider?

Comment: scrapy crawl parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a glance, there are **4 things I would suggest you change** that could potentially enhance the chances your `spider` runs returns properly the scraped data back :

1)
`callback='parse_item'`, **--->** `callback=self.parse_item`

2)
`allowed_domains = ['www.eksisozluk.com']` **--->**  `allowed_domains = ['eksisozluk.com']`

3)
`'title': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-date permalink']/text()").getall(),` **--->**
`'title': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-date permalink']/text()").getall()`

4)
`follow=True, )` **--->** `follow=True)`

Correcting all the above, your code becomes:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class ParserSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'parser'
    allowed_domains = ['eksisozluk.com']
    start_urls = ['https://eksisozluk.com/basliklar/gundem']

    rules = (
        Rule((LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths="//ul[@class='topic-list']/li/a")), callback=self.parse_item, follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath("//h1[@id='title']/a/text()").getall(),
            'entry': response.xpath("//div[@class='content']text()").getall(),
            'yazar': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-author']/text()").getall(),
            'title': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-date permalink']/text()").getall()

        }
```

Also, I would suggest keeping your main `callback` function to be named `parse()`, because if a Request doesn’t specify a callback, the spider’s `parse()` method will be used,  i.e `scrapy` is looking for a method called `parse()`.

Comment: hello mate, unfortunately it outputs another error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: thats a killer solution as well.. thx for your help mate, it was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I change `allowed_domains` https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html. Miss Match your target url and allowed_domains url.

```
class ParserSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'parser'
    allowed_domains = ['eksisozluk.com']
    start_urls = ['https://eksisozluk.com/basliklar/gundem']

    rules = (
        Rule((LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths="//ul[@class='topic-list']/li/a")), callback='parse_item', follow=True, ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath("//h1[@id='title']/a/text()").getall(),
            'entry': response.xpath("//div[@class='content']/text()").getall(),
            'yazar': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-author']/text()").getall(),
            'title': response.xpath("//a[@class='entry-date permalink']/text()").getall(),

        }
```